# java.io.IOException: Invalid argument

Tags: java, cluster-computing, ioexception

I have a web application running in cluster mode with a load balancer.
It consists in two tomcats (T1, and T2) addressing only one DB.
T2 is nfs mounted to T1. This is the only dofference between both nodes.

I have a java method generating some files. If the request
runs on T1 there is no problem but if the request is running on node 2
I get an exception as follows:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:279)
```

The corresponding code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataFileList.size(); i++) {
    outputFileName = outputFolder + fileNameList.get(i);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);                        
    fileOut.write(dataFileList.get(i), 0, dataFileList.get(i).length);
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
}
```

The exception appears at the fileOut.close()

Any hint?

Luis

Comment: Can you write files normally from the OS of T2 (ie. outside of Java)?

Comment: Yes, I can. Moreover, when the exceptio nin thrown an empty file is generated.

Comment: Yes! I can write at the file system directly from a shell. Moreover. An empty file is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason.
First I've notices that NOT always this exception comes
at the same point.

Sometimes was a 
    java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:279)
                                    ^^^^^

and sometimes was

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:260)
```

Therefore the problem is NOT a java problem. Not even a NFS problem.
The problem **is** the underlying File System type which is an DRBD 
file system.

Testing at a shell to write across the nodes works if one is writing a small
file. I.e:

at the nfs mounted node

```
cd /tmp
date > /shared/path-to-some-not-mounted-dir/today

will work
```

but

```
cat myBigFile > /shared/path-to-some-not-mounted-dir/today
```

will deliver the following error

```
cat: write error: Invalid argument
```

Therefore the solution is to use other type of file system, gfs for example.

Answer (score 3):

Setting this line in the `.profile` resolved the issue:

```
ulimit –n 2048
```

Answer (score 1):

How large do dataFileList and fileNameList get?  You could be running out of file descriptors.  It's odd that it happens on close(), though.

Comment: I am generating one or two files only.
The most interesting thing is that from the node which is directly attached there is no problem (same volume) but when trying to write to the node which is NFS mounted the exception appears.