# Android Bluetooth l2cap connectNative java.io.IOException: Invalid argument

Tags: android, bluetooth, arguments, l2cap

I am writing a Bluetooth app for Android.I use android l2cap api by reflection.
But I received error report on some devices(it works properly on some other devices).

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:220)
```

So what's problems?

Comment: This would help u..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780543/java-io-ioexception-invalid-argument

Comment: any success? need any help writing your native driver? I was considering attempting the same thing.